# Counting a layer in multi MXD using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers, count

I try to count how many times the layer "frame" occurs in 3 MXD files.

The layer "frame" (this is the layer name in the table of contents) occur in "project1" (this is the first MXD file)- 1 time.

In "project2"- it occur 2 times.

In "project3"- it occur 3 times.

I'm using this python code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
counter = 0
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname 
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):                                   
            if lyr.name == "frame":
                counter = counter + 1
    print counter
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

But i get this incorrect result:

```
>>> 
project1.mxd
1
project2.mxd
4
project3.mxd
6
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reset your `counter` variable to 0 every time you iterate over a new mxd, otherwise `counter` will count the cumulative occurences of 'frame' layers. Create a new `counter` variable for each iterated mxd by moving it inside the for loop (it will overwrite the previous one):

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    counter = 0
    print mxdname 
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):                                   
            if lyr.name == "frame":
                counter = counter + 1
    print counter
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Answer (score 3):

As @GISGe says, you need to reset the counter inside the loop.

Also, instead of

```
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if lyr.name == "frame":
                counter = counter + 1
```

You could 1) use the wildcard argument in ListLayers, and 2) just check the length of the returned list.

```
counter += len(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "frame", df)
```

I'm not sure what this line is doing btw, as df is overwritten in the loop below it.

```
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
```